# cancel ajax success function from inside ajaxSuccess event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a global `ajaxSuccess` event and a local `success` function attached to an ajax request.

I want to cancel the `success` function if the global find `status = false` in the response.

like this

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr) {
    let result = xhr.responseJSON;
    if (result.status === false) {
        //here the ajax should be stopped, I don't want to call the local functio
    }
}
$.ajax(url, {
    'method': method,
    'success': function () {
        //success function to call if the global ajaxSuccess is ok
    }
})
```

can this be achieved ?

Comment: The simplest thing would be the add that check to the local success method. Is there some reason you don’t want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an insight into what you may be looking for. You will need to return the backend data in json.

why don't you set status to certain values
Eg. **false= 0** and **true = 1**. You can then print success or failure based on values returned from the backend  in this sample from PHP backend.

Here am sending a post variable with value of **test_ok**. If the value is **test_ok** then alert success else alert fail and 
stop further action

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var test ='test_ok';
var datasend = "test="+ test;

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'test.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(result){

                $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);

                               if (result.status ==0) {
  alert('failed');
return false;
    }



                               if (result.status == 1) {
       alert('success');
    }


            }

        });

});


</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

$test = $_POST['test'];
$output = array();


if($test == "test_ok"){

$output[] = array(
"status" => '1'
);

}
 if($test != "test_ok"){
$output[] = array(
"status" => '0'
);

}


echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: I am not asking about the backend nither how to set an alert in success functions ...